# Configure datapipeline to receive parameter values from a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline, data-pipeline

I have a Lambda function that activates a datapipeline:

```
client.activate_pipeline(
    pipelineId='df-0680373LNPNFF73UDDD',
    parameterValues=[{'id':'myVariable','stringValue':'ok'}])
```

How do I configure the datapipeline to receive the parameterValues at activation. I want to pass the parameter value 'ok' to a ShellCommandActivity via Script Argument for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AWS Datapipeline` you create parameters/variables & define its usage at time of putting pipeline definition. 

Then parameter values can be either provided at same time `put-pipeline-defintion` or can be overridden at time of `pipeline-activation`.

If parameter is declared as `myVariable`, it can be referred inside pipeline object as `#{myVariable}`

```
client.put_pipeline_definition(
        pipelineId='myPipeline',
        pipelineObjects=[
            {
                'id': 'CreateDirectory',
                "type" : "ShellCommandActivity",
                'name': 'CreateDirectory',
                'fields': [
                    {
                        'key': 'command',
                        'stringValue': 'mkdir #{myVariable}'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        parameterObjects=[
            {
                'id': 'myVariable',
                'attributes': [
                    {
                        'key': 'description',
                        'stringValue': 'The directory to be created'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],


client.activate_pipeline(
    pipelineId='df-0680373LNPNFF73UDDD',
    parameterValues=[{'id':'myVariable','stringValue':'ok'}])
```